# Finding prime factors of a number using "for loop" in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, prime-factoring

I know how to implement this using a while-loop, but I need to figure out a solution using a for-loop.  For a given num = 56 my code below outputs `[2, 7, 4]`, whereas the right answer would be `[2,2,2,7]`. where am I going wrong?

```
def prime_fac(num):
    a = num
    pf = []
    for x in range(2,a):
        if a % x == 0:
            if x == 2 or x == 3:
                pf.append(x)
                a = a//x
            else:
                for y in range(2,x):
                    if (x % y) == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    pf.append(x)
                    a = a // x
        else:
            continue
    if a>1:
        pf.append(a)
    print (f"Prime factors of {num} are {pf}")
number = int(input('Enter a number to find its prime factors: '))
prime_fac(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the algorithm, not so much the Python code. Your program increases the divisor `x`, when it divides `a`, without checking, if `x**i` (i>1) divides `a`. In your output, the last number represent a product of all prime numbers that are more than once a divisor of `a`. You could employ debuggers like [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to find out, where your program does not, what you expect.

Actually, I just wanted to give you the pseudocode to improve your algorithm, so you could implement the algorithm. But then I noticed, that the pseudocode was pretty much the same in Python:

```
def prime_fac(num):
    a = num
    pf = []
    #ranges in Python don't include the last element, therefore we need a + 1 to detect also prime numbers
    for x in range(2, a + 1):
        #check if x is divisor and repeat
        while a % x == 0:
            pf.append(x)
            a = a // x

        #all factors found?
        if a == 1:
            #yes, return list with prime factors
            return pf 
        #no, go to next x
```

And now, you can try to improve the efficiency of your algorithm because this strategy is rather slow.